# Using NSRegularExpression results

Tags: objective-c, regex, expression

I'm trying to use a regular expression to divide a string in various parts, separated by, for example, tabs. I want to store each part somewhere else, so my question is how to correctly use all the results from the regular expression? 
lets say my regex is this:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?:\t|^)([^\"\t]+|\"(?:[^\"]|\"\")*\")?"
                                options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:string
                                options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
```

I read my file one line at a time (need to do this for a reason), so this is the part of the code I'm using to search each line for the substrings:

```
for(int i=0;i<[myFile numberOfLines];i++){

        aRow = [[myFile fileRows] objectAtIndex:i];            

        NSArray* results = [regex matchesInString:aRow options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [aRow length])];
        for (NSTextCheckingResult* result in results) {

            NSString* resultString = [string substringWithRange:result.range];
            NSLog(@"I should be storing this as a correctly separated word:\t%@",resultString);
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong/missing? the results printed are not showing what I think they should be showing...
(myFile / fileRows / numberOfLines / current row / aRow work correctly and contain what they are supposed to, checked, double checked and triple checked before posting)

**extra info:**
input file:

```
 number letter  data    something
 1  g   dvsfg   sdf
 2  az  "dbfghe fgh"    s
 4  b   wdf fghfgh
 3  c   sdgy    fdgh
 5  d   egfn    dkjfghfgkhj
```

Returns (NSLog-wise:)

```
_____________number letter  data    something
 _____________number    letter
 _____________numbe
 _____________r da
 _____________a 
 _____________number    letter  
 _____________number    letter
 _____________number    letter  data    s
```

in stead of:

```
number
letter
data
something
1
g
dvsfg
```

... etc (you get the point, each tab separated "word"  in a different NSLog message)

Comment: What does the input look like? What should your pattern do (or is that obvious)? What output do you get and what output do you expect?

Comment: original question edited, added the requested info. thanks for the fast reply so far :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `NSString* resultString = [aRow substringWithRange:...`? I.e. `aRow` instead of `string` in that line?

Comment: that was it, thank you very much for your help!

PS: I have edited the original regex as I had a small error there too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my above comment:

```
NSString* resultString = [string substringWithRange:result.range];
```

should be

```
NSString* resultString = [aRow substringWithRange:result.range];
```

Comment: Sorry, just saw the check mark thing, thanks again for your help!